# Stop submission of PopModular extender on enter key press

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a popupmodular extender whenever the user presses enter on the popupmodular the modular closes on it on and no action takes places I want to stop this behavior as this is breaking my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding default submission buttons on each pop-up extender.